# PXE E51 No DHCP or proxy DHCP offers were received for WDS set up

Tags: wds

I'm hoping someone could help me with WDS, I currently have a 5 PC set up which one PC is the Windows 2012 R2 server and that connects to the other four PCs via a switch which all PCs can ping one another on static IPs.

On my server I have the roles DHCP, AD DS, DNS, windows assessment and deployment kit and WDS set up and configured. However when I try to actually deploy I get the error:

PXE E51 No DHCP or proxy DHCP offers were received

I feel that this may be a port issue, however I'm not able to do anything outside of the two server options of not listening to the DHCP port and using the proxy service. I tried to change the port through the admin tools fire wall, but the OS won't let me make any changes. Any know how else to go about changing the ports?

I also haven't configured the switch, not sure if I need to change anything on that.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: You've got WDS installed on the DHCP server, you need to make an additional configuration to WDS. See the *Co-hosting DHCP and WDS On The Same Server* section of this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/system_center_configuration_manager_operating_system_deployment_support_blog/archive/2011/10/14/troubleshooting-the-pxe-service-point-and-wds-in-configuration-manager-2007.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing it sounds like you need to configure `WDS` to work in sync with your `DHCP` server. `WDS` itself is a `DHCP` server, `PXE` server and `TFTP` server. It uses the `DHCP` part of `WDS` to identify the platform/hardware and `PXE/TFTP` to boot the computer.

To configure your `WDS` server, go to the `WDS` `MMC (Microsoft Management Console)` and open the properties box for your server.[image: Right click and press properties]

Next go to the `DHCP` tab and check the appropriate boxes. In your case it should be both boxes. The top one tells the `WDS` server that there is another `DHCP` server on the computer. The second one tells it if it is a microsoft server, so that it could auto configure the `DHCP` server (if supported).
[image: Configure to your current setup.]

---

## TL;DR:

Configure the `DHCP` tab of the `WDS` properties to match your current `DHCP` setup.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not in the same vlan than your WDS, check if you use a dhcp relay agent, if yes add an ip dhcp relay agant with your wds ip address

Bye